# How to call a list of Urls and console.log response in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

Hi I have a lambda that runs every hour. All it is meant to do is send a get response to a list of urls and console.log the response.

How do I do this with promises in nodejs when some of the URl calls will not succeed but I still need to log them as well?

Below is an example of the code I have now

```
function pingAll() {

    try {
        urls = fs.readFileSync(('./apiURLS/list.txt'), 'utf8').split('\n');
        for(var i = 0; i<urls.length;i++) {

            var url = urls[i];
            http.get(url, function(res) {
                console.log("Got response: " +url + " "+ res.statusCode);
            }).on('error', function(e) {
                console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
            });

        }
    } 
    catch(e) {
        console.log('Error:', e.stack);
    } 
}
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: you need every response to be consoled?

Comment: You've described what you want to happen and shown us some code, but you haven't told us what the problem is. Why do you think the code you have isn't suitable?

Comment: Well if that functions runs it will make several async http requests then the function will end its run and any responses that havent come back yet will not be logged

Comment: And yes I need to see what the status is for each URL, each url is an api gateway

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By no means an expert, there may be better solutions out there, but I think you may achieve this with Promise.all!

Like this

```
const urls = fs.readFileSync(('./apiURLS/list.txt'), 'utf8').split('\n');

var ping = function ping(url) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    http.get(url, function(res) {
            console.log("Got response: " +url + " "+ res.statusCode);
            resolve(res);
        }).on('error', function(e) {
            console.error("Got error: " + e.message);
            reject(e.message);
        });
  });
};

var pingAll = urls.map(ping);

var results = Promise.all(pingAll);

results.then(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
}).catch(err => {
  console.error(err);
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much that was perfect

Answer (score -1):

Try to put the try/catch into the for statement:

```
function pingAll() {
    try {
        urls = fs.readFileSync(('./apiURLS/list.txt'), 'utf8').split('\n');
        for(var i = 0; i<urls.length;i++) {
            var url = urls[i];
            try {
                http.get(url, function(res) {
                    console.log("Got response: " +url + " "+ res.statusCode);
                }).on('error', function(e) {
                    console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
                });
            }
            catch(e) {
                console.log('Error calling url:', e.stack);
            } 
        }
    } 
    catch(e) {
        console.log('Error:', e.stack);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Why? The request (a) doesn't throw an exception if it fails and (b) is async so it would be too late to catch it even if it did

Comment: He doesn't explain which the problem is, an async request didn't throw an exception I know, but perhaps http.get yes (before starts request), then the following urls won't be tested. Your (b) case has no sense.